# Pass json from js to controller

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Data doesn't passing to controller, always null

My script in view:

```
function deleteRecords() {
    var selected = [];
    $('#myTable input:checked').each(function () {
        selected.push($(this).attr('id'));
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: '/Home/DeleteRecords',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: { "json": JSON.stringify(selected) },
        error: function () {
            alert("Error!");
        }
    });
}
```

My home controller method:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult DeleteRecords(string AllId)
{
    return null;
}
```

Comment: You have to make your ajax call and your controller's action matching with the same type. If you send a "number" from ajax, your action must receive a "number" (int, decimal, ...). Here, your `selected` variable is an array of strings, so, you must modify your action to get an array of strings (IEnumerable<string>, string[], ...).

Comment: Since it's a "delete" action from method name, why not do a HttpDelete like

    [HttpDelete, Route("{allId}")]
    public IActionResult DeleteRecords(string AllId)
    {
        return null;
    }

then in you javascript

    $.ajax({
        url: '/Home/DeleteRecords' + selected,
        type: 'DELETE'
    });

it's much more clean and you follow standards...
Post are for creating a new entity..

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ, still does not work :(

Comment: @Adrian Look at the answer from arslanaybars

Comment: @Joshlo is right. You should use Delete type on ajax request and HttpDelete in action. But before do that you need to enable delete verb before. have good work.

Answer (score 3):

send ajax request data like below,

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Home/DeleteRecords',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: JSON.stringify(selected),
    error: function () {
        alert("Error!");
    }
});
```

and receive the data in action like

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult DeleteRecords(string[] AllId)
{
    return null;
}
```

It need to pass the action. Hope it helps to you.

Comment: If it is correct, could you mark the answer as correct? @Adrian

Comment: Unfortunately method receives an empty array

Comment: can you write to console.log(selected) after pushing

Comment: Array [ "e94c0a26-95ec-40d1-9dc1-fcbd4f4c33c3" ]

Comment: @Adrian did you change string AllId to string[] AllId. Be carefull action parameter type is string[]

Comment: It should work @Adrian. still didn't pass to action ?

Comment: I also created a project and i did some its work. parameter pass to action. what did you change after my answer. maybe you escaped a point

Comment: I just replaced my code by your) have not idea why it is don't working

Comment: If selected variable is not null. It should pass. sorry but no idea if it isn't.

Comment: @arslanaybars you also need `[FromBody]` parameter binding attribute. core is more explicit when it comes to parameter binding.

Comment: @arslanaybars, 500 internal server error in console

Comment: @Adrian delete this line dataType: 'json', then it wont has an internal error

Answer (score 0):

Name your property in the Post the same as your method so that the automatic binding picks it up. - Turns out this doesn't matter for single object.

The data Object you were creating was not parse-able by .net, use JSON.stringify directly for the data payload.

Note: The change in Home controller since you are passing an array of string.

```
function deleteRecords() {
var selected = [];
$('#myTable input:checked').each(function () {
    selected.push($(this).attr('id'));
});

$.ajax({
    url: '/Home/DeleteRecords',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: JSON.stringify(selected),
    error: function () {
        alert("Error!");
    }
});
```

}

For your home controller method:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult DeleteRecords(string[] AllId)
{
    return null;
}
```

Comment: nope, it is don't work. 500 internal server error in console, i have no idea

Comment: fixed it up for you, even did a test this time :)

Answer (score 0):

with the code in your question, try below to get the json

```
System.Web.Context.Current.Request.Form["json"]
```

if you want some more graceful stuff, you need to put FromBody attribute in your parameter signature

```
DeleteResults([FromBody] string json)
```